# How to change screen resolution when installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: display, vmware, display-resolution

It has made me like a fool. I'm installing ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso on a VMware workstation 12 VM, and I'm trapped at selecting time zone.

Screenshots below:

The first sight of the time zone UI is ok.

[image]

Click *Continue*, and something bad happens. Next screen is Keyboard Layout, and *UI right-side is cropped . I click the partially visible button(red arrow marked), in hope that it is *Next*, but no luck. It just bring me back to time-zone selection UI, and this UI is now also right-side cropped.

[image]

[image]

The Ubuntu installer uses default screen resolution 800*600. If I could change it to 1024*768, it may have a chance to display correctly. Could some one tell me how to?

BTW: My host machine's screen size is much larger than 800*600(main monitor is 1920*1200).

====== George provides a nice workaround ======

Mouse-dragging the UI window title lets me see the whole scene.

[image]

Comment: you can `try Ubuntu` instead `install Ubuntu now`

Comment: please use your cursor to move the installation window to the left so you can see the buttons. AFAIK you can't  do this while installing.

Comment: @george would this be worthy of a real answer?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix will post that ASAP

Comment: @JimmChen posted an answer please accept, glad it worked out.

Comment: @JimmChen echoing George's request please upvote as well :)

Answer (score 2):

When installing Ubuntu at times depending on your system the `installation window` might not be seen clearly. This can't be changed during installation so simply use your cursor to move the `installation window` to the left of your screen so you can see the `buttons`.

With this this I believe you should be able to access and accept all that is required to get the installation to the end.

Comment: I can only move it left down and right, but I need to move it up :(

Answer (score 0):

if you cannot see your window. you can try holding ALT (or CMD when using a mac keyboard) while dragging the window around the visible space.